# Find_all_siblings is not finding all table row siblings from forum post in Python Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, siblings

I am web scraping a forum. However, the same code scrapes all 15 posts from one page but only 12 posts on the second forum page. This second forum page also has 15 posts. I don't understand why it's not scraping all the posts.

```
first_tr = page_soup.find_all('table' ,{'class' : 'forumline'})[0].select('tr')[2]
all_tr = [first_tr] + first_tr.find_next_siblings('tr')
```

I output `all_tr` and found that it was missing the last three table rows for the second forum page. Is something wrong with my `find_next_siblings`?

Comment: Post a problem that we can reproduce. For starters, add the URLs for which the code works and for which the code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I used the wrong html parser.